# Server Socket Compilation Error

Tags: c++, sockets, compiler-errors

I having trouble debugging the following code, which is throwing a typecast error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
   int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
   struct sockaddr_in server ,client;
   char *message;

   //create socket;
   socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
   if (socket_desc == -1)
   {
      printf("Could not create socket");
   }

   //prepare sock addr structure
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

   //bind
   if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(&server)) < 0)
   {
      printf("bind failed");
   }
   printf("Bind done");

   //Listen
   listen(socket_desc , 3);

   //accept incoming connection
   printf("Waiting for incoming connection ... ");

   c =sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockadrr *)&client,sizeof(&client));
   while(new_socket < 0);
   {
      puts("Connection Accepted");
      message = "Hello Client ...Recieved your message \n";
      write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));
   }

   if (new_socket < 0)
   {
      perror("accept failed");
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

> `error: cannot convert 'main(int, char**)::sockadrr*' to 'sockaddr*' for argument '2' to 'int accept(int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)'`

Comment: As a first step, [format your code properly please](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26001546/edit)!

Comment: @DevarshDesai `/OT` THX. Yeah, I love the philosophical concept. And it saved me from a lot of grief and disappointments, about how things are going. Head's up ;) ... `/OT`

Comment: Make sure to paste in the error instead of typing it in. Your typed in version did not have the typo that is present in your source code.

Answer (score 4):

### The fish:

You have a typo.

```
new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockadrr *)&client,sizeof(&client));
                                         ^^^^^^^^ should be sockaddr
```

Because of the typo, the unknown type `struct sockadrr` was scoped into the function, in this case `main`. So, `main(int, char**)::sockadrr` is what showed up in the error message.

### How to fish:

The error points out that you cannot convert `sockadrr*` to `sockaddr*`. By carefully comparing the two strings, it becomes clear that the two types are indeed different. In this case, the difference happens because of a misspelling due to a typographical error.

```
sockadrr*
sockaddr*
      .
     /|\
      |
```

When the compiler complains about "cannot convert", or "invalid conversion", this indicates you are providing a type that is incompatible with what is expected. Carefully examine the type you are providing in your code, and determine what is the more suitable type that should be used instead.

Comment: thank you @jxh ... but now its throwing a error of "initializing argument 3 of int accept(int,sockaddr*,socklen_t*) [-fpermissive]

Comment: The 3rd argument should be a pointer to a `socklen_t`. The result of `sizeof` operator is a `size_t` value.